# How do I restrict users to download videos from my website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mpeg-dash, mpd

I am trying to upload my videos such that no one can download videos from my website but can watch online only. I have tried solving this by DASH, but somewhere I'm not getting right way to do it.

Comment: Why did you put them on a website then?

Comment: Thank you to inform me. Actually I want to make it publically, but it cannot be downloaded. Or if it is downloaded then it should not play. I guess there must be something to encrypt video. :)